# Java JFrame MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, mouselistener

I have a JFrame with small squares set as background. Squares are pictures.
Amount of squares depends on JFrame size, so I use ArrayList and I add JLabels to JFrame using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++){
   add(squares.get(i));
}
```

I want to write a method so when mouse enters square it would change its color.
I have implemented MouseListener. However this does not work(it works with normal JLabels):

```
ArrayList<JLabel> squares = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
```

.
.
.

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

        if(source == squares){
            System.out.println("AAA");
        }

        if(source == squares.get(0)){
            System.out.println("BBB");
        }
}
```

My question: How do I get element out of ArrayList, so I could set it equal to source and if its equal to source do something?

Comment: Can you try casting it into JLabel object and find it on your squares list? Like `if(squares.contains((JLabel)e.getSource)) { System.out.println("AAA");}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However this does not work(it works with normal JLabels):

This statement does not make sense. A JLabel is a JLabel. As long as you add the label to the frame it should work. The fact that you created an ArrayList as well doesn't affect how the label works on the frame.

```
Object source = e.getSource();
```

You already have the source, so all you need to do is cast it to a JLabel:

```
JLabel enteredLabel = (JLabel).getSource();
enteredLabel.doSomething(...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I feel like an idiot I forgot to do .addMouseListener to my JLabels, haha